# What is the difference between absorbance and absorption in the context of wavelength?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference, terminology

I'm writing a paper that discusses wavelength. 
Which is correct: **maximum absorbance** or **maximum absorption**?

I guess both **absorbance** and **absorption** are used in the context of wavelength but which to use depends on what is meant. 
 Am I correct? 
 If correct, what is the difference between these two terms?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*X has maximum absorbance* means X has the maximum ability to absorb something, as in capacity.  The amount of something actually absorbed may be less than the maximum.

*X has maximum absorption* means X absorbed all it can take.  We may or may not know the maximum capacity, but if we know it can't absorb any more, we just found that out.

Comment: Thank you!  So now **maximum absorption** or **absorption maximum** would be the right term for what I mean, which is an actual amount.

I have one more question left, the order of the two words...
Google search gave similar numbers of hits (when searched in combination with "optical density").

Comment: Maximum goes first.